# to find a person's descendants of a binary family tree (scheme lang)

Tags: tree, scheme, family-tree

this is a scheme program to find the descendants of a binary family tree (the tree    has only fathers and two sons - bst) when a person's name and the tree is given as input. I think the main problem here is the getsons function. What should I replace this function with?

```
(define (getfather FAMT)`
  (car FAMT)
   )


 (define (getson1 FAMT)
  (cadr FAMT)
 )

 (define (getson2 FAMT)
  (caddr FAMT)
 )

 (define (getsons FAMT)
 (cdr FAMT)
 )

 (define (empty? FAMT)
 (null? FAMT)
 )

(define (nosons? FAMT)
 (and (empty? (getson1 FAMT)) (empty? (getson2 FAMT)))
)

(define (getd FAMT)
 (cond ((empty? FAMT) '())
       ((nosons? FAMT) '())
       ((empty? (getson1 FAMT)) (getson2 FAMT))
       ((empty? (getson2 FAMT)) (getson1 FAMT))
       (else (getd (getsons FAMT))))
 )

(define (main1 person FAMT)
 (cond ((empty? FAMT) (getd '()))
       ((equal? person (getfather FAMT)) (getd FAMT))
       (else ( main1 person (getsons FAMT))))
 )



(define FAMT '(Pierce (Mark (Peter () ()) (Blaise () ())) (James () () )))

</code>
```

Comment: The question doesn't specify _how_ are the descendants supposed to be returned. As subtrees? as a list of names? In my answer I assumed the latter, if that's not correct you just have to change the way of _combining_ the answers, using whatever you need instead of `append`

Comment: The descendants were supposed to be returned as a list of names. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `getd` and `main1` are incorrect. In `getd`, the cases where one of the sons is missing must recursively call `getd` on the other son, and the `else` case must recursively call `getd` on *both* sons and combine the answer. And anyway, the solution is too complex, only two cases are truly required, either the tree is empty or is non-empty, the whole trick lies in knowing how to combine the answers from both subtrees, I chose to append the elements to create an output list:

```
; returns a list of all descendants, including node at the root
(define (getd FAMT)
  (cond ((empty? FAMT)
         '())
        (else
         (append (list (getfather FAMT))
                 (getd (getson1 FAMT))
                 (getd (getson2 FAMT))))))
```

Similarly, `main1` must combine the results of both sons once a person is found, and it must keep recursively looking on both sides of the tree and combine its answers, because we don't know at which side is the searched person (the tree doesn't seem to be sorted):

```
; finds a person and returns a list with all of
; its descendants, the list excludes the person
(define (main1 person FAMT)
  (cond ((empty? FAMT)
         '())
        ((eq? person (getfather FAMT))
         (append (getd (getson1 FAMT))
                 (getd (getson2 FAMT))))
        (else
         (append (main1 person (getson1 FAMT))
                 (main1 person (getson2 FAMT))))))
```

Finally, you should use larger trees for testing, the sample tree in the question doesn't cover all possible cases, for instance:

```
(define FAMT 
  '(Pierce
    (Mark 
     (Peter 
      (Logan () ()) 
      ()) 
     (Blaise 
      () 
      (Kurt () ())))
    (James 
     ()
     ())))

(main1 'Mark FAMT)
=> '(Peter Logan Blaise Kurt)
```